# Multiple moor files in one flutter project

Tags: flutter, sqflite, flutter-moor

How can we generate multiple moor files in flutter project ?

I have 2 dart files, with 2 references for g.dart.
When I run the builder command, moor only generates 1 g.dart file and does not create the other. How to generate both of the g.dart files?